# How to apply a color gradient to a bar plot using Plots in Julia

Tags: julia

I have this bar plot:

```
bar(source_country_n.WeaponSourceCountry, source_country_n.nrow, legend=false, title="Nuclear Explosions by Country", xlabel="Country", ylabel="Number of Explosions", palette=cgrad(:matter, 7, categorical=true))
```

Applying `palette=cgrad(:matter, 7, categorical=true)` isn't working. It seems to apply only the first color in the gradient like this:

[image: current plot]

I want each bar to have a **different color** based on the categorical gradient.

How to correctly apply a categorical gradient to a bar plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a work around, pass colors in as an array:

```
cs = collect(cgrad(:matter, 7, categorical=true))

bar(source_country_n.WeaponSourceCountry, source_country_n.nrow, legend=false, title="Nuclear Explosions by Country", xlabel="Country", ylabel="Number of Explosions", palette=cs)
```

for example:

```
bar(1:3, rand(3),  c=collect(cgrad(:matter, 3, categorical=true)))
```

[image]